# PHP match tables from 2 different MySQL Databases

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this PHP Code:

```
$sql="SELECT * from client where level = '100' group by parent_client_id ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$pbx01_conn);
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    $sql2="SELECT * from customer where customerid = '".$result["parent_client_id"]."' ";
    echo $sql2.'<br>';
    $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($rs2) > 0)
    {
        $result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2);
        echo $result2["company"].'<br>';
    }
}
```

I am trying to match the `parent_client_id` column in the client table with the `customerid` column in the customer table.

the customer and client tables are in 2 different databases.

I want to display the `company` column from the client table if there is no match between the two

can i do this using php?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT company FROM db1.client LEFT JOIN db2.customer ON db1.client.parent_client_id=db2.customer.customerid  
WHERE customerid  IS null
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **databasename.tablename** syntax if your tables are in different databases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.company FROM client c INNER JOIN customer cu ON cu.customerid = c.parent_client_id WHERE c.level = '100' GROUP BY c.parent_client_id
```